# IdentityServer4 - Loading login page in iframe

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I need to change CSP in response that contains login page from IdentityServer4 in order to render that page in iframe in my client app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/indice-co/Indice.AspNet/tree/master/samples/CodeFlowInlineFrame) you can find a sample MVC application where we have implemented a login mechanism to an IdentityServer4 instance using the authorization code flow but using an iframe. The flow is not that different from redirecting to the authority. Using an iframe just hides the redirection from the user which some believe provides a better user experience.

Regarding IdentityServer4 you need to add the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive to the CSP. Also it would be good to configure your IS4 not to display a logout prompt, so you can have a seamless logout experience.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code again. It's not avaiable anymore. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The authorize endpoint will already allow this but the login page is under your control so it should be just a matter of setting the CSP header yourself via an MVC filter or similar.

Be aware though that if you use federation to other providers it will likely not work as their CSP will almost certainly not allow your origin as a frame-ancestor.